# I keep getting Thread 1: single SIGABRT. I tried everything

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

It says that a button linked to a view controller is causing the problem.

Code told me this:

[image]

Error in the Code:

[image]

Comment: You need to add more information to your question — more details about the error and its context, and more of an example of the code that is triggering the error.

Comment: your question is not clear  , add more information

Comment: To learn how to debug a crash, see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: You need to add more info

Answer (score 0):

`SIGABRT` is most commonly associated with errors associated with connections. The way I would go about solving this is to inspect the connections attached to that button in question. If you don't see any obvious error in those connections, delete and reconnect them as necessary.

If that button in question didn't work out, begin reconnecting the rest of your UI elements from the storyboard. Anything with a connection could be the cause of this; Even connections set on constraints.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  I need help on this!

Comment: Did you actually go through all your outlets?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is `Signal SIGABRT` when you delete an outlet and put it back in without deleting the old one in the connection inspector (in the Interface Builder). If you go on the connections inspector and see a sort of exclamation point, delete it and put it back in and it should work fine. Here's an image:

[image]

It could also be that you forgot to connect one of the labels in the View controller to the Main Storyboard. This will be the case if you see an empty circle in the ViewController.